# How do I make the "Firewall Rule Delete" command assigned to the right mouse button detect the path of the file?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, firewall, firewall-rules

I have created a custom property for the right button menu that allows me to "**Firewall Rule**" any file in Windows 10 and block its internet access.

Similarly, I have another property that can disable or delete the rule I created.
However, I encountered a small problem.

The property works as intended, but it "**deletes all rules with the same name**".
It does not take into account the path of the file, only its name.

How can I modify the code below so that it only deletes the rule for the specific path?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall]
@=""
"MUIVerb"="Windows Firewall"
"icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\FirewallControlPanel.dll,0"
"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Add Blocking Rule (Outgoing)]
@=""
MUIVerb"="Add Blocking Rule (Outgoing)"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\FirewallControlPanel.dll,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Add Blocking Rule (Outgoing)\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -Executionpolicy ByPass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoLogo -Command \"start powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList \\\"-NoLogo -WindowStyle Hidden -command `\\\"New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName ([System.IO.Path]::GetFilenameWithoutExtension('%1')) -Name '%1' -Enabled True -Direction Outbound -Action Block -Program '%1'`\\\"\\\"\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Delete Rule (Outgoing)]
@=""
MUIVerb"="Unblock Rule (Outgoing)"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\FirewallControlPanel.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Delete Rule (Outgoing)\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -Executionpolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoLogo -Command \"Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \\\"-NoLogo -WindowStyle Hidden -Command `\"& {netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name='\"'([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('%1'))'\"' dir=out}'%1'`\\\"\\\"\""
```

I would appreciate any help or guidance on this issue. Thank you for your attention and interest in advance.

Comment: Change `'([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('%1'))'` to `'$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('%1'))'`

Comment: Hello @MathiasR.Jessen , I applied the change; but it still removes the rules for other files of the same name that are in different path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using *just* `name=...` in a `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule` call deletes *all* rules by that name.
- To limit deletion to those rules by that name that target a *specific executable*, you must add a `program=...` argument.

Using the tips regarding PowerShell's CLI syntax below, try the following in your `.reg` file:

```bash
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Delete Rule (Outgoing)\command]
@="powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")) program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\" dir=out'"
```

**Important**:

- As in your question, the above uses `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` to get the input file's *name without the filename extension*, e.g., `some` for `C:\Users\jdoe\some.exe`; to *keep* the extension, use `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName()` instead.
- To assist in troubleshooting, I have removed `-WindowStyle Hidden` from the `Start-Process` call and have added `-NoExit` to the *nested* `powershell.exe` call.
- This will open the elevated session *visibly* and *keep it open*, so that you can inspect what happens.
- Running `[Environment]::CommandLine` in the session will show you the exact process command line that the nested, elevated `powershell.exe` process saw; e.g., you'll see the following after invoking the shortcut-menu command on file `C:\User\jdoe\some.exe`:

  ```bash
  "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\"C:\Users\jdoe\some.exe\")) program=\"C:\Users\jdoe\some.exe\" dir=out
  ```
- The above translates to the following `netsh` call (note the absence of `"..."` quoting, because, when PowerShell - of necessity - rebuilds the process command line behind the scenes, it employs *on-demand* double-quoting: only if the argument contains *spaces* does it get enclosed in `"..."` - invariably *as a whole*):

  ```bash
  netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=some program=C:\Users\jdoe\some.exe dir=out
  ```

---

**General tips** regarding the **PowerShell CLI** and the necessary escaping:

- There's *no* reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly.

  - Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.
  - In no-shell invocations, such as in your case, even the `"..."` enclosure isn't necessary, which is why it was omitted below for simplicity.

    - There's a largely hypothetical concern when omitting the `"..."` enclosure with respect to *whitespace normalization*, which would only apply if *embedded strings* with *multiple* adjacent whitespace characters had to be passed *as-is*.
- There is *no* reason to use `-NoLogo` in CLI calls that use `-Command` in order to suppress the startup banner; `-Command` *alone* does that (it also isn't necessary when using `-File`, *unless* `-NoExit` is also specified).

  - However, it *is* generally worth adding the `-NoProfile` switch parameter, which suppresses loading of any [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), which are typically only useful in *interactive* sessions; not loading them both improves performance and makes for a more predictable execution environment.
- Getting the escaping and quoting right in your case is exceptionally difficult, given that there are multiple layers of interpretation to deal with:

  - The `.reg` file format in which `\` must be used to escape `"` chars. as well as verbatim `\` itself.
  - *Two* layers of interpretation by [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, due to requiring a *nested* call via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb Runas` in order to launch an *elevated* PowerShell session.

    - *Each* PowerShell CLI call itself has *two* layers of interpretation:

      - *Unquoted* `"` chars. are *removed* during *command-line processing* - unless they're escaped as `\"`.
      - The result is then interpreted *as PowerShell code*.

Comment: Thank you for the information @mklement0.
When I tried to +1 the thread, I thought it would disapprove because it said it needed 15 reputation.
I have now confirmed/accepted.

And I asked another related question.
I've added a description with the code I tried.
Thank you for everything.