# How can I assign the "Action=Allow" command after the "Delete Firewall Rule" command assigned to the right button?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, firewall, firewall-rules

There is a `Context Menu` that I have assigned to the right mouse button as `Windows Firewall`. And I am using the following code to delete a security rule.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall]
@=""
"MUIVerb"="Windows Firewall"
"icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\FirewallControlPanel.dll,0"
"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Delete Rule (Outgoing)]
@=""
MUIVerb"="Delete Rule (Outgoing)"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\FirewallControlPanel.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Delete Rule (Outgoing)\command]
@="powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")) program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\" dir=out'"
```

And likewise I want it to re-add this code as `"action=allow"` with a single script after deleting.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall]
@=""
"MUIVerb"="Windows Firewall"
"icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\FirewallControlPanel.dll,0"
"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Allow (Out)]
@=""
MUIVerb"="Allow (Out)"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\FirewallControlPanel.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Windows Firewall\shell\Allow (Out)\command]
@="powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")) program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\" dir=out; netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name='\"'([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('%1'))'\"' dir=out action=allow program='\"'%1'\"'}'%1'`\\\"\\\"\""
```

**Other commands I tried**

1)

```
@="powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\"%1\")) program=\"%1\" dir=out; netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name='\"'([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('%1'))'\"' dir=out action=allow program='\"'%1'\"'}' \"%1\""
```

2. 

```
@="powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command \"netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")) program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\" dir=out; netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\\\\\\\"$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('%1'))\\\\\\\" dir=out action=allow program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\"\"'\""
```

`Powershell` opens when I run the code; but it skips the `Administrator Permission (UAC)` prompt before it opens.

I'm not sure exactly; but I think somewhere in the code one or more of these signs `"\'` are missing or more.

I would appreciate any help or guidance on this issue. Thank you for your attention and interest in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax considerations at play in your `.reg` file value in combination with a call to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, are discussed in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609327/45375) to your previous question.

To adapt the value shown there to your new use case:

- Model your additional `netsh` call on the existing, functioning one that is embedded in the larger command line in the first snippet in your question.
- In isolation, this gives you:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")) dir=out action=allow program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\"
```

- Now use `;`, PowerShell's statement separator, to append this call directly to the functioning one, which means that it goes *just inside the closing `'`* (i.e. before the closing `'` of the `'...'` string that encloses the positionally implied `-ArgumentList` value of the `Start-Process` call):

```
@="powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")) program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\" dir=out; netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\")) dir=out action=allow program=\\\\\\\"%1\\\\\\\"'"
```